# How safe is to delete already removed ConcurrentHashMap element?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, concurrenthashmap

In case of following code, run by multiple threads:

```
private static final Map<String, keyinfo> mapKeys = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, keyinfo>();

private static void purgeOldKeys() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, keyinfo> key : mapKeys.entrySet()) {
        if(key.getValue().createTime + keyCacheTime < getCurrentDBTime())
            mapKeys.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Can I avoid the synchronizer?

Or because removing already removed element, is not defined according to JavaDoc, the synchronizer will be still required?

Comment: I don't think you can do this regardless because of the fail fast iterator that the for loop is using.

Comment: Yep, this code won't work even with a single thread!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when *removing* from a collection, it is much cleaner (and faster!) to use a full `Iterator` API instead of the lazy "foreach" notion.

The `iterator.remove();` will not invalidate the iterator; and it knows the position it was at. Use this pattern:

```
for (Iterator<> iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<> entry = iter.next();
    if (testRemoval(entry))
        iter.remove(); // <----- remove using the iterator position!
}
```

It's faster because it does not involve *searching* the object again. It's more robust, because the iterator knows the object has been removed. In many collections, the code you showed above will "fast fail" because of a concurrent modification.

Comment: Thanks, guess I grew too much accustomed to Idea error checker :). Still, the question remains - do I need to synchronize the whole block in case multiple threads have called this function, or remove will fail silently without causing any trouble (again, the docs say the behavior is not specified).

Comment: The docs say for `remove(key)` "This method does nothing if the key is not in the table." - I'd expect the iterator.remove to behave the same. So why not give it a test run? Your code above does not look as if it would do damage if it fails anyway.

Comment: From Java docs: The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method. So if another thread modifies this, what can happen? The code is a part of more extensive thread, and can impact some operations if it fails

Comment: By the way, any chance the above example will always miss the 1st element? I.e. always jump to next() element before the check.

Comment: The `next()` call is the *proper* way to get the first element. And `iterator.remove();` is the best you can do to remove. At least for non-concurrent hash maps: yes, another thread may trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`, and yes, you should then be prepared for that. The ConcurrentHashMap version seems to have snapshot semantics maybe - an element returned by `next()` *might* already be deleted, and you might miss elements that were added in the meantime.

Comment: Why would this fail fast? isn't this a CocurrentHashMap it shouldn't have any problems using it as a for() no need for iterators

Comment: `for(Object a : collection)` is just a shorthand for using an `Iterator`. See Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2 the compiler translates this to an `Iterator` based loop (for `Iterable`; for arrays it compiles to an `int`-loop). And if you have an `Iterator` anyway, use `remove`. It's both faster and safe.

Answer (score 4):

1) This code can't remove anything because there's a bug in it - `mapKeys.remove(key);` - key in your code is in fact a Map.Entry. It should be

```
for (Map.Entry<String, keyinfo> e : map.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getValue().createTime + keyCacheTime < getCurrentDBTime())
            map.remove(e.getKey());
    }
}
```

2) As for removing entries while iterating over ConcurrentHashMap it is safe, ConcurrentHashMap.entrySet API

```
The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException
```

and this test confirms it

```
    Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "2");
    map.put("2", "2");
    map.put("3", "3");
    for (String k : map.keySet()) {
        map.remove(k);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

prints

```
{}
```

Comment: I tested before answering :)

Comment: +1 spot on.  Yeah the OP's choice of the field `key` being a `Map.Entry` is very unfortunate.